# How to grant access to specific nodes to anonymous users?

Tags: nodes, hooks

My site has a front page, an 'about us' and 'T&C' pages which are all created as 'basic page' types, and I want to allow anonymous users to access them. I have tried this hook below, but it does not seem to work because I am always redirected to the login page (using LoginToboggan if that matters).

```
function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;

  if ($type == 'basic page' && $op == 'view') {
    return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
  }
  else {
    return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
  } 
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need content access to roles by content types, you can try using [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module.

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role
>   and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete
>   permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable per
>   content access settings, so you can customize the access for each
>   content node.

Comment: I had seen it, thanks, but I want to try to avoid adding a new module where I could write ten lines of code for the same result (hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

Type is the machine name of the content type and content type name with space is replaced by _ . And drupal default basic page machine name is page . Please try the below code :

```
function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;

  if ($type == 'page' && $op == 'view') {
    return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
  }
  else {
    return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
  } 
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that 'basic page' type is actually called 'page' by Drupal. It still does not work though.

Comment: @Pierre_colin If this doesn't work, you may have some other code preventing the node access.