# How do I give access permission for specific node to anonymous User

Tags: 8, nodes

I have removed "Access Content " Permission from Anonymous user. Now want to display specific node to the anonymous user.

As this is for only 1 or 2 nodes, It's not a good idea to use a contributed module like https://www.drupal.org/project/access_by_entity. I am looking for a solution as a custom code only

I have tried mymodule_node_access also but it's not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restrict access to some nodes based on roles or users?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250128/how-to-restrict-access-to-some-nodes-based-on-roles-or-users)

Comment: I have updated the question, It's not a kind of a duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250128/how-to-restrict-access-to-some-nodes-based-on-roles-or-users

Comment: Poosible DUplicate is https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/216885/how-to-grant-access-to-specific-nodes-to-anonymous-users

But above one is for drupal 7 and also don't have answer.

Comment: you can use hook_preprocess_page ,then check for  anonymous user and page url arguments in condition,then redirect page to 404 or somewhere

Comment: "I have tried mymodule_node_access". Your question is too broad if you don't include the code of mymodule_node_access or your attempts so far. Otherwise there are too many possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An access hook can't change the result once you have forbidden access by removing the permission "Access Content", see [Is there a way to add node grants to anonymous users?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/242571/is-there-a-way-to-add-node-grants-to-anonymous-users#comment297092_242571).

If you don't want to grant this permission, because it controls much more than node access, another approach might be to setup a route which bypasses permissions and checks the node ID instead:

*mymodule.routing.yml:*

```
mymodule.my_nodes:
  path: '/path_to_my_nodes/{node}'
  defaults:
    _entity_view: 'node.full'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
    node: (123|124)
```

Answer (score 1):

Give back the "Node access" permission (View published content) to Anonymous user and control the accesss with your custom module

```
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

function MODULENAME_node_access(NodeInterface $node, $op, $account) {
  $allowed = [1,2];
  if ($op == "view" && in_array($node->id(),$allowed)) {
    return AccessResult::allowed();
  }
  return AccessResult::forbidden();
}
```